# Is there a list what datatype corresponds to the system_type_id in Sys.columns

Tags: sql-server

Is there a list what datatype corresponds to the system_type_id in Sys.columns. I am looking for an easy way to examine the columns we have in the database and i would like to avoid the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes you can look in [`sys.types`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188021.aspx) for such a list or use the [`type_name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189750.aspx) function to look up an individual type_id.

Comment: Definitely easier than my post. But not quite as fun :) Thank you though.

Answer (score 4):

system_type_id is not unique in sys.types because user types can reuse system type. To get a list of unique system types, you can select rows where system_type_id = user_type_id. They equal only for system types.

```
SELECT system_type_id, name
FROM sys.types
WHERE system_type_id = user_type_id
```

Comment: _"`system_type_id` is not unique in `sys.types` because user types can reuse system types"_ - yes, but doing `WHERE system_type_id = user_type_id` is not sufficient because some system types are aliases, e.g. both `sysname` and `nvarchar` have `system_type_id = 231`.

Comment: UPDATE: Ah, the _correct_ way to handle duplicate `sys.types.system_type_id` values when looking at column types is to do `FROM sys.columns AS c INNER JOIN sys.types AS t ON c.system_type_id = t.system_typeId AND c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id`.